Access Database file size reduction - Sharepoint back end
I have an Access database linked to Sharepoint. This works very well but the file size of the database file .accdb is large: 2GB large!
The main tables have only around 750 entries, mainly containing contact information and not much else. There are related tables to this and a little code but nothing extensive.
I originally thought the large file size was because of a long text field that I use for notes. I have since stored these in rtf files in each record's library that loads when a form is loaded and have deleted the field from the tables and relinked. Unfortunately, the size of the file is still 2GB and I do not know why even after compacting and repairing. I expected that the file size would be drastically reduced.
I have kept the original "offending" tables as copies in Sharepoint in case they are needed but they are not linked.
Is there any way of checking what could be causing the file to be so big?

Try creating a new (empty) database, and then import all object from that large database. At general usage, 750 records cannot result in 2GB file size.

2 GB is the maximum size of an Access DB. Try repair and compact. this should help. You can also set the option to compact as closure of the DB.
Background: when you delete data, Access will mark it just as deleted and does not show it anymore. Therefore the DB size will not shrink when you delete something. Just when you choose compact and repair, Access will create a new Db in the background and copy all records and objects which are not deleted in the new DB and rename it to the original name. This new DB should then be smaller.

Gustav is right, there's no easy way to estimate the size of objects in Access. I've used code similar to this, but tracking the change in file size of the destination database each time an object is copied. That only results in a rough estimate, as Access may extend the file beyond what a specific table needs, then not grow at all for a subsequent small table. It would need to be adjusted for linked tables. Also, you might try switching around the caching mode for SharePoint tables, that can have a major impact on file size.

what is the size of the database after doing a compact + repair?

You may have embedded image resources for form controls and backgrounds (there should be many large images to add up to 2GB). The best approach is already mentioned by Gustav.

I did what @Gustav suggested and copied all objects over to a blank DB. The old DB did not want to play ball with some. Formatting is stuffed, but not a major problem. New size: 10.7MB. After compacting and repairing: 7.18MB.

@AlbertD.Kallal: after compacting and repairing, size of old DB was still 1.99GB. I was not even able to decrypt the DB as resources ran out.

@ShahramAlemzadeh There were a few icons that were embedded. Around 5. I cannot see how this could be such a factor.
Still, I do not know why the original DB grew so large considering the records.
